# How to show alert choosing subcategory when parent dropdown not selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in coding and learning from the internet how to code.
I have two dropdowns. 1st one is Parent Dropdown and 2nd is Sub-Category Dropdown.

[image]

I want to show an alert message when Parent dropdown not selected and user directly click on sub-category dropdown. The message will show, "You must select the parent category".

[image: Here I want to show alert, You have to select parent category!]

For this purpose I have tried value= onclick confirm ('You must select the parent category') on select this is whant I want but the problem is that whenever I click on sub-category this alert always come. I have tried onchange as well but this also not work for me.

I also tried to count index length.val but this also not working.

I also tried below script but that also not work for me.

```
   <script>
   var dropdown = document.getElementById("child");
   dropdown.onchange = function(event){
   if(dropdown.value==""){
     alert("Your message")
   }
   }
   </script>
```

Please have a look at what I am doing with my code.

```
 //This is what I code 
 <script>
 function get_child_options(){
 var parentID = jQuery('#parent').val(); 
 jQuery.ajax({    //Inside jQuery we create ajax object
 url:'/halfdrink/adminseller/parsers/child_categories.php',
 type:'POST',
 data: {parentID : parentID },                                  
 success: function(data){
 jQuery('#child').html(data);    },
 error: function(){alert("Something went wront with the child options.")},

 });
 }

 // This also the main code line where I call get_child_options
 jQuery('select[name="parent"]').change(get_child_options); 
 </script>
```

I am definitely doing something wrong but don't know what I am doing wrong.
 Your suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work with jQuery. PHP code not needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name="child"]').change(function(){
    var elem = $('select[name="parent"] option:selected').val();
    if (elem == 0) {
      $('select[name="child"] option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true);
      alert("You must select the parent category!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Parent*:</label>
<select name="parent">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">Parent 1</option>
  <option value="2">Parent 2</option>
</select>

<label>Child*:</label>
<select name="child">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">Child 1</option>
  <option value="2">Child 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have learned from your solution but unfortunately, it did not work for me. Because in your answer when I click on child and select child 1 then child 1 is selected and it shows on the subcategory. I want when I touch the subcategory and the parent not selected then alert will show and child do not show the options until parent is selected.

Comment: Add this line before alert: `$('select[name="child"] option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true);` See my snippet.

Comment: Thank You so much gabor. Now the code works fine. This is exactly what I wanted. I tried it from the day before yesterday. Thank You so much dear!